# How to draw a code block in LaTeX as in Markdown?

Tags: pdftex, tcolorbox, mdframed, framed, markdown

Code blocks are frequently used in Markdown as shown in the picture below. I am wondering whether there is a way to display the same thing in LaTeX, namely an auto-sized, shaded, rounded-corner box around a word.

Thank you in advance!

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.  This site works best when you start out with some work that we build on.  You tagged this with `tcolorbox` and `mdframed`.  What have you found looking into those packages?  Do you have a minimal (almost) working example that we can start with?

Comment: If you don't insist on the rounded corners, you have the very simple `\colorbox{somecolour}{contents}`. You also can do that with `\psframebox` from `pstricks` (rounded cprners withe the option `linearc=radius`.

Comment: The code from the proposed duplicate might seem a bit complicated, but of course you can define a new command using this code to simplify your input.

Comment: @Marijn Thx Marijin! That's exactly what I am looking for!